# Javascript changing button and onClick issue

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

I am trying to use an onClick event in JavaScript and am running into a problem. I want to make a button that changes its id, click handler, and text back and forth when it is clicked - I want it to become a completely different button when clicked the first time, but then revert back to the original button when clicked the second time.

My idea was to write one event handler for the original button being clicked which changes it to the second button and I put this in the function "change()". I also had planned on writing one separate event handler for the new button being clicked which changes it to the original button and I put this in the function "changeBack()".

The problem is that when I click on the original button one time, change() gets called and within it changeBack() *automatically* gets called exactly when the onClick is defined for the new button and right before the innerHTML is changed. I commented out some of the original lines and put an alert in to illustrate this unwanted behavior. I think somehow the click is still active when the new button gets created, thus forcing it to call changeBack() even though the new button was never clicked. Any help on this would be great. Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change() {
        var x = document.getElementById("button");
        x.id = "alternateButton";
        x.onClick = changeBack();
        x.innerHTML = "Click to Change Me Back";
    }

    function changeBack() {
        var x = document.getElementById("alternateButton");
        alert('hi');
        //x.id = "button";
        //x.onClick = change();
        //x.innerHTML = "Click Me";
    }   
</script>

<button id="button" onClick="change()">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Events are bound to the elements and not to the ID attribute. So `change` method is always executed when you click it.

Comment: @Sushanth Thank you for the response. This makes sense. I should have stated I am actually pretty new to JavaScript. If I understand correctly, what I want to do then is bind a *different* event to the button upon clicking it. Is this correct? Also, I am still confused as to why changeBack() gets called.

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to do. Is your intent to just change  the button text on click

Comment: I want to change the text and also change the behavior on the click event. For example, if I click on the button the text on the button will change and I will also add functionality to change other elements on the page - for example a paragraph farther down the page. When I click the *new* button I want to change the text on the button back to the original, and unchange the recently changed elements on the page (the previously changed paragraph)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events are bound to the elements and not to the ID attribute. Both the handlers are always executed when you click the button.

Also it is a good idea to avoid binding handlers using inline event handlers.

```
// Find the elemnt
var btn = document.getElementById('button');
// Data attribuet to keep tab of whether it is clicked or not
btn.dataset.clicked = "1";
// Attach event
btn.addEventListener('click', change);

function change() {
    var txt = 'Click to Change Me Back';
    // Will give you the truthy/falsy value
    if(!!this.dataset.clicked) {
        this.dataset.clicked = "";

       // First implementation

    } else {
        this.dataset.clicked = "1";
        txt = "Click Me";

        // The other case
    }
    this.innerHTML = txt;
}
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rkneksx2/)**

Answer (score 0):

The above comment by Sushanth got me started on the right track by using a truth tester. However, the same problem about the mouse came up - it captures the mouse longer than I want it to (even when using onmousedown). Because of this, right when the new button gets created the old one replaces it, so the new button is never seen. Also, by changing the element's id, I ran into some really strange things such as the program stopping completely if I use an alert - and not continuing after I close the alert, but when I delete the alert, the entire program runs. I guess it's better to leave the ID's alone and only use them as a reference and change the styles dynamically with DOM access rather than the style tag and control other parts of the page using the button by referencing other functions in the switch statement (I'm really new to JavaScript so I'm not sure how else it is done).

Because of these issues but with Sushanth's comment idea, I used *two* testers: one for which button is currently being shown, and one for the mouse having been pressed or released. I also had some strange issues when putting the code in the header instead of the bottom of the body. Finally, I had to use some custom properties. I hope this helps anybody that wants to use a button that changes its appearance and functionality back and forth as you click on it.

```
<button id="button1" onmousedown="transformButton1()" onmouseup="release()">Click Me</button>

<p id="one">One</p>
<p id="two">Two</p>
<p id="three">Three</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
var x = document.getElementById("button1");
x["clicked"] = 0;
x["released"] = 1;

function transformButton1() {
var x = document.getElementById("button1");

if (x["released"] == 1) {
    switch (x["clicked"]) {
        case 0:
            x["clicked"] = 1;
            x["released"] = 0;
            // Other function calls to change other elements on the page, for example:
            document.getElementById("two").innerHTML = "I've Changed!!!!!";
            x.innerHTML = "Click to Change Me Back";
            break;

        case 1:
            x["clicked"] = 0;
            x["released"] = 0;
            // Other function calls to change other elements on the page, for example:
            document.getElementById("two").innerHTML = "Two";
            x.innerHTML = "Click Me";
            break;
        }
    }    
}

function release() {
    document.getElementById("button1")["released"] = 1;
}
</script>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dj4jptqg/1/)

Comment: It is never a good idea to change the ID Attribute.. i would avoid that as it would cause confusing issues.  Also the reason your code does not work if you put the script in the head is because when the script is encountered, the script is read first and the DOM is not processed yet. It fails to note the existence of the element. So the events are not bound. But in the above code snippet it works fine as the script is after the element is encountered. So it works fine